# Callback function when the Paypal transaction is successful

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I have integrated Paypal in my software and I have the callback function through ´notify_url´ attribute.

However, the callback through notify_url is not getting called. Here is the paypal code I am using :

```
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"return\" value=\"".$this_script."?action=success\"/>\n";
    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"cancel_return\" value=\"".$this_script."?action=cancel\"/>\n";
    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"notify_url\" value=\"".$this_script."?mode=paypal\"/>\n";
```

[image]

The paypal transaction is successful, however, the notification URL is not getting called. Any idea how to fix it ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to work with paypal's IPN?

Comment: Yes, That is correct.

Comment: Okay first check if your notify url is working when paypal IPN sends a notification using [IPN Simulator](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/ipn_simulator)

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly from the IPN simulator. But, when I use it through sandbox, the callback url through notify_url is never called

Comment: Please see my answer below. Hope it helps you , that's all the answer that fixed my IPN problems. Regards

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with IPN before:

So here are the following things that I did:

Check if paypal IPN sends notification to my notify_url using [IPN Simulator](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/ipn_simulator)

> a.)Your page should allow paypal IPN notification
>
> b.) Your notify_url link is correct

If all are met above and IPN is still not working then there should be problem a problem in your configuration check your paypal configuration for validating IPN

Not this using port:80

```
$fp = fsockopen('ssl://'. $url_parsed['host'], '80', $err_num, $err_str, 30);
```

But this using port:443

```
$fp = fsockopen('ssl://'. $url_parsed['host'], '443', $err_num, $err_str, 30);
```

And that should fix all for paypal's IPN notification.

Please take note also that there's a problem with IPN notification not working in sandbox see my reference before [here](https://drupal.org/node/1901256) (a bit old but in the same year)

Hope it all helps you